# zoomed-in via button click on web view iPad app

Tags: ipad, uiwebview

In web view  my code is`static float i=1.5;

```
if(i<=7.5)
{
    [btnZoom setEnabled:YES];
    objWebView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1+i,1+i);
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.0f];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    i=i+1.5;
    NSLog(@"i===============%f",i);
}

if(i==7.5)
{
    NSLog(@"i===============%f",i);
    [btnZoom setEnabled:NO];
    i=1.5;
}
```

`objWebview` is the object of web view.my scales page to fit property of webview is clicked but I have to zoom in on the button click. *(I am new in iPhone)*

By this code it is getting zoomed-in, but my webview contents are getting blurred when zoomed in.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to zoom your UIWebView by codebase.

### Zoom UIScrollView available in UIWebView

This option will applicable from iOS 5.0 and >

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  NSString *urlAddress = @"<website url address here>";
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
  NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]
  [webView loadRequest:requestObj];  
  webView.delegate = self;
  webLookupView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
}
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)theWebView
{
  CGSize contentSize = theWebView.scrollView.contentSize;
  CGSize viewSize = self.view.bounds.size;

  float rw = viewSize.width / contentSize.width;

  theWebView.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = rw;
  theWebView.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = rw;
  theWebView.scrollView.zoomScale = rw;  
}
```

### Zoom Webpage itself

In UIWebViewDelegate method [– webViewDidFinishLoad:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

```
NSString *jsCommand = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.body.style.zoom = 1.5;"];
[theWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCommand];
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: thanx for the code. I have applied it but my web view is still getting blurred on the zoom-in. is there any other way to do this? webview is taken through the xib.

Comment: If still it is getting blurred than I guess its problem with the webpage. That particular webpage is not compatible with that much zoom level. (Its just a guess). If feasible can you provide that webpage url.

Comment: hey! Mrunal 
my web view contents are comming from the database. i am not using any  url. but still i want to make u sure through the code. my code is here..

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    [objWebView loadHTMLString:objDatabaseForFetures.feature_detail baseURL:baseURL];

i am using the objDatabaseForFetures.feature_detail as url and taking the NSbundle because the images which are comming with the web view text are in the bundle. this code is working for the ios4 and iOS 5 but not running for iPad app.

Comment: Have you written this? - webLookupView.scalesPageToFit = YES;

Comment: my scalesPageToFit property is checked in xib so i think it don't need to be set again in the code. is it  compulsory to write it agin in the code...?

Comment: Not required to do it again. Then some other issue is there.